# MongoDB select's/find seems to have the same performance for a larger amount of data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java, database

I'm measuring the performance of MongoDB with its native driver.
For the insert operation, the more I inserted the more time it took. However, with selecting, I have 500.000 documents (inside 1 collection) with each document having 4 other embedded, small documents inside of it.

I performed a select query using also a conditional operation for 1 subdocument. The performance of selecting 100 documents (from a total of 1000) is 0,007 ms while selecting 50000 documents (from a total of 500000) is 0,008 ms.

I don't quite understand how this is possible. Is it really that fast? I'm measuring the performance using JMH.

Comment: A wild guess would be that you perform a query without any indexes so the database needs to scan the full collection anyway. But to make sure please perform your queries with [`.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to get more information about index usage of your query and add both your query and the explain output to your question.

Comment: Another guess would be that you only measure the time to open a cursor but not the time to actually retrieve the data from the cursor. Please post your code, otherwise your question can not be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment mate. I updated my question. I will try the .explain() now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test setup only measures the time it takes to open a cursor, but not to actually read any data from the cursor.

When you perform `contactCollection.find(bs);` the database returns a cursor object but doesn't actually do anything yet. The actual query doesn't happen before you retrieve the data from the cursor. Changing the line to `contactCollection.find(bs).toArray()` should force the database to return all results, allowing you to measure both the query-time, the time it takes to pass the results via network and for the Java driver to parse the results.

Alternatively you could use `contactCollection.find(bs).explain()` to measure the time the operation takes only on the database-level and also get a DBObject with some useful performance metrics from the database itself.

Comment: Thank you mate. I always thought the find would be enough to  measure but didn't realize it wasn't doing anything other than returning a cursor object. It is around 5000 milliseconds now which seems more accurate. Is the toArray() method however something fair to measure inside this operation?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! It's really clear! I will use the explain method! :)

Comment: Pretty amazing how quickly it can fetch results so quick (using explain() gives me around 1000 ms).